# How to assign shell command to key?

Tags: scripting, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, window-maker

I want to assign my script to special key on my keyboard. xmodmap recognize this key as XF86AudioMute, but I want to execute my script when it pressed. How to do it?

My window manager is Window Maker, but I am looking for a solution independent of wm.

Answer (score 2):

For years I have used [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/) with WindowMaker and other window managers - it'll do everything you need. Here's an example [blog post](http://www.epiguru.com/2012/06/how-to-create-keybindings-on-linux-with-xbindkeys-and-xvkbd/) with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a detailed guide to add new keyboard shortcut over [there](http://windowmakerandi.blogspot.ru/2013/02/get-productive-in-window-maker-keyboard.html) in "Adding a Custom Keyboard Shortcut" section.

Quote with a quick description:

> Most "custom" shortcuts are used to launch specific applications, so I
>   will describe the process with that goal in mind. To add your own
>   keyboard shortcut for an application, go to the "Applications Menu
>   Definition" panel in the Preferences app.  Select the application item
>   in the menu for which you want to create a shortcut, then use the
>   "capture" button to capture the keystrokes you want to assign to that
>   item.

Comment: Yes, but this shortcut is visible in menu - but I want to add shortcut higher - independently of wm